# dvd - not able to read

Tags: windows-7

I can open most DVD's ( Windows 7) but am not able to load one from Jaguar Automobile Company.

Windows explorer sees' all of the files on the DVD but will not open any of them.

Any suggestions   -  DVD says it needs Windows 95; and Adobe Reader v6.0  -

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed software to handle DVD Playback? Try installing VLC media player and checking again.